# Flash light on something

Tags: word-usage

In a dark room, you flash the spotlight. So if you flash it on a particular thing, is the use of this sentence natural:

> Hey! Flash the light on the table (and what about: Hey! Can you flash some light here?)
>
> I flashed the light on the table.

Is the use of "flash" natural in this context? If not then what can be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Flash the light on the table" is a perfectly reasonable sentence, but may not have the meaning you're looking for.

> **flash**
>
> to shine suddenly and usually brightly, but only for a short time:

[*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/flash)

So, "flash the light on the table" would mean *briefly direct the light at the table, then move it away, or turn it off*.

If you want the light to be turned on and to stay on, try: "**Shine** the light on the table"